# Use quantile to get percentile in r

Tags: r, cut, quantile, percentile

I am trying to classify my data to 3 groups between 30th and 70th percentile, Previosly was easy for me to sahre my data by equal groups like my code below prove.

```
MV_UK$`1993` <- with(MV_UK, cut(MV_UK$`1993`, breaks = quantile(MV_UK$`1993`, probs = seq(0,1 , by= 0.5), na.rm = TRUE), include.lowest = TRUE , labels= c("S","B") ))
```

I tried to this code

```
  MV_UK$`1992` <- with(MV_UK, cut(BTM_UK$`1992`, breaks = quantile(MV_UK$`1992`, probs = c(.3,.7) , na.rm = TRUE), include.lowest = TRUE , labels= c("L","M","B") ))
```

But I get an Error

```
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you provide some sample data. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically what the error says - 
In the second example, you are providing 2 groups (probs = c(.3,.7)), which is fewer than the amount of labels you provide (c("L","M","B"))

Notice that in your first code snippet,
    seq(0,1 , by= 0.5)
You generate 3 distinct values (0.0, 0.5, 1.0)

So you can either add another cutoff point, or remove a label.

Comment: Thank you was very helpful I find the answer,     BTM_UK$`1992` <- with(BTM_UK, cut(BTM_UK$`1992`, breaks = quantile(BTM_UK$`1992`, probs = c(0,.3,.7,1) , na.rm = TRUE), include.lowest = TRUE , labels= c("L","M","B") ))